# Function's parameter that is a pointer to an argument that was declared as const, how to handle it?

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, constants, function-parameter

I'm using MikroC for PIC, I don't know the name of the compiler. I'm using a PIC18F4550. I need to print a list of itens of a menu in a 16x4 LCD. I put here a slice of code, because the code is big to put it here, so, I tried to write here a minimal reproducible example.

The code works in the following whay: I have a stack to store the menus, the menu structure has fields as title and number of itens.

**In file main.c**

```
#include "menu.h"

int main(){ 
  unsigned char error;
  error = 0;
  Tstack stackMenus;

  error = menu_push(&stackMenus, &mainMenu);

}
```

=========================================================

**In file menu.c**

```
#include "menu.h"

const Tmenu mainMenu = {
  4,
  "Main Menu"
};

unsigned char menu_push( Tstack *s, PTmenu item ){
  unsigned char error = 0;

  if(s->topo == 9){
    return 1;
  }
  s->pilha[++s->topo] = item;
  return error;
}
```

======================================================

**In file menu.h**

```
struct Smenu {
  unsigned char numberOfItens;
  char *Title;
};
typedef struct Smenu Tmenu;
typedef Tmenu *PTmenu;

struct Sstack {
    PTmenu stack[10];
    signed char top;
};
typedef struct Sstack Tstack;

extern Tmenu mainMenu;

Terro menu_push(Tstack *s, PTmenu item);
```

I declared  mainMenu as const, as pass it as argument to menu_stack. However, the compiler complains saying it is a "Illegal pointer conversion".
I tryed to do

```
unsigned char menu_push( Tstack *s, Tmenu * const item ){ ...}
```

and

```
unsigned char menu_push( Tstack *s, const Tmenu * item ){ ...}
```

But the same message appears,  "Illegal pointer conversion".

How can I handle that ? I need to declare the mainMenu as const because there are others menus and I'm using a microcontroller with a restricted RAM memory size.

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]. In other words, give us a complete, but minimal, set of code (with no `...`) so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: BTW, I just put together a [mcve] based on the code in the question, and it works fine.

Comment: The third notation — `Terro menu_stack( ..., const Tmenu * item ){ ...}` should be usable as long as the prototype is in scope before the call is made.  Did you change the header as well as the function definition?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes. It is in a .h file that was included. I will update the post to meet the minimal reproducible example cited above.

Comment: The message "illegal pointer conversion" isn't one I recognize, so it probably isn't GCC that you're using.  Which compiler are you using?  The most likely error from GCC would be "conversion discards const qualifier" or thereabouts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I'm using MikroC for PIC, I don't know the name of the compiler. I'm using a PIC18F4550

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — TL;DR, the answer is generally "No" with possible exceptions for function pointers.  Mixing `const` with `PTmenu` will give you headaches (it gives me headaches); don't do it.  Roughly: `const PTmenu` is the same as `Tmenu * const`, IIRC.  Use the explicit `const Tmenu *` notation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I did it. I suspected that too, but this made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code compiles cleanly under reasonably stringent compilation options.  There were quite a lot of trivial changes needed to convert your native language code to the translated English framework.  However, I've eliminated `PTmenu` as a type (as hinted in comments) — the answer to [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) is generally "No".

#### `menu.h`

```
typedef unsigned char Terro;

struct Smenu
{
    unsigned char numberOfItens;
    char *Title;
};
typedef struct Smenu Tmenu;

struct Sstack
{
    const Tmenu *stack[10];
    signed char top;
};
typedef struct Sstack Tstack;

extern const Tmenu mainMenu;

Terro menu_push(Tstack *s, const Tmenu *item);
```

#### `main.c`

```
#include "menu.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char error;
    Tstack stackMenus = { { 0 }, 0 };

    error = menu_push(&stackMenus, &mainMenu);
    printf("Error = %d\n", error);
}
```

#### `menu.c`

```
#include "menu.h"

const Tmenu mainMenu =
{
    4,
    "Main Menu"
};

unsigned char menu_push(Tstack *s, const Tmenu *item)
{
    unsigned char error = 0;

    if (s->top == 9)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    s->stack[++s->top] = item;
    return error;
}
```

Test compilation (to object file) with GCC 9.1.0 on a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c menu47.c
$
```

There are still issues with the code — the line `if (s->top == 9)` is diabolical.
It should be more like `if (s->top < 10)` except that the `10` should be a name the identifies the size of the `stack` array in `Tstack` — I'd probably use a variant on `enum { STACK_SIZE = 10 };` and then use that in the array dimension and in the test.  That name is a bit too generic for comfort — it could too easily collide with other stack sizes.  But that depends on your use case and is taking us far afield.  There should be header guards in the `menu.h` file (`#ifndef MENU_H_INCLUDED` / `#define MENU_H_INCLUDED` / …contents of header… / `#endif`).  Capitalization of structure elements is haphazard.  The variable `error` in `main()` should probably be of type `Terro`.  The return type of the function in `menu.c` should match the declaration in `menu.h` — it should be `Terro` too.  Etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! Was very kind of you to compile the code. As I said, I already tried to compile without use a pointer as a type. But I did it for some variables, not all. Now, that you reaffirmed this issue, I did it again, but now I eliminated all typedef pointers of the code. The code not compiles yet, but the message changed, now appears:  "initialization image not found for mainMenu". I don't know why it is happening, but I think it happened because I initialized mainMenu outside of any function. Could be it the problem ?

Comment: But, I need to create it outside a function because the menus need to be global. And if I do it const I can't modify it inside a function after creation.

Comment: I solved the last problem, initialization image not found for mainMenu. It was different in declaration in .h and .c . Sorry.